# Different execution time with date hardcoded or not on oracle query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have this query :

```
select  PROP_CREATED_DATE , 
    TVS_CHANNEL.TVS_DESCRIPTION CHANNEL, 
    CASE OVM_CATEGORY   WHEN '9'  then 'BIKE'
                        WHEN '10' then 'BIKE'
                        WHEN '11' then 'BIKE'
                        ELSE 'CAR'
        END AS PRODUCT, TVS_ACTION.TVS_DESCRIPTION BROKER, APV_ACTION_REFERENCE
from ad_proposals
inner join ad_proposal_versions on PROP_REFERENCE = APV_PROP_REFERENCE  
inner join ad_proposal_objects  on POB_APV_PROP_REFERENCE = APV_PROP_REFERENCE 
                            and POB_APV_VERSION_NUMBER = APV_VERSION_NUMBER
inner join ov_motors    on OVM_OBJ_ID = POB_OVM_OBJ_ID
                    and POB_OVM_NUMBER = OVM_NUMBER 
INNER JOIN table_values TVS_CHANNEL on TVS_CHANNEL.TVS_CODE = PROP_CHANNEL and TVS_CHANNEL.TVS_TAD_CODE = 'CHANNEL'
left outer join table_values TVS_ACTION on TVS_ACTION.TVS_CODE = APV_ACTION_REFERENCE and TVS_ACTION.TVS_TAD_CODE = 'EBROKERID'
where APV_CREATED_DATE >= add_months(trunc(sysdate),-1)
and APV_VERSION_NUMBER = 1 
and APV_ORIGIN_TYPE = 'NBV'
```

It is not really complicated, but i am facing an issue that i don't understand. 
see this line 
`where APV_CREATED_DATE >= add_months(trunc(sysdate),-1)`

If i change it by `where APV_CREATED_DATE >= DATE '2015-05-31'` I have my result almost instant, there is an index on APV_CREATED_DATE which is a date column. 
But with the function `add_months(trunc(sysdate),-1)`, I run the query and do get any answer even if i wait for an hour...

The only difference on plans are here :

```
INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX JAPHONIE.AD_PROPOSAL_VERSIONS_IDX5;  Optimizer=Analyzed;  Search_columns=1;  Cost=1;  Cardinality=2;  Cpu_cost=8,666;  Io_cost=1;  Access_predicates="ad_proposal_versions"."apv_created_date">=add_months(trunc(sysdate@!),-1);  Time=1             
INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX JAPHONIE.AD_PROPOSAL_VERSIONS_IDX5;  Optimizer=Analyzed;  Search_columns=1;  Cost=1;  Cardinality=2;  Cpu_cost=8,666;  Io_cost=1;  Access_predicates="ad_proposal_versions"."apv_created_date">=to_date(' 2015-05-31 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');  Time=1
```

If you have any idea so i can make this query works, that would be great

Comment: That is really weird.  Have you tried using `tkprof` to gather more performance data on your queries?

Comment: @sstan i will check that. I didnt know this function. I just hope i have the priveleges to do that on prod which is not sure.  I'll let you know ;)

Comment: As @sstan says, it is really, really weird. The only possibility I see is that  add_months(trunc(sysdate@!) and to_date(' 2015-05-31 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') are not the same value. Check if your system clock is properly set or check if your session has a different NLS parameter (maybe territory) than your server. You can check both at the same time with: select add_months(trunc(sysdate@!),-1) - to_date(' 2015-05-31 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual; It must return 0 if everything is ok, and something different if system clock or NLS parameter are not properly set.

Comment: well `SQL Statement which produced this data: select add_months(trunc(sysdate@!),-1) - to_date(' 2015-05-31 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual` →　`0 `　　－　I still dont know what is happening, even the DBA doesnt understand. But I found a workarroun : I use them both at the same time as `add_months(trunc(sysdate),-1)`
will always be higher than `DATE '2015-05-31'`

Comment: Not sure I understand your workaround, I'm curious. Back to your original problem: can you reproduce this odd behavior on a test database?  Or is it only in your production database?  If it's only your production database, here is a terrible suggestion that DBAs around the world will probably hate me for... ask your DBA to run this statement once: `alter system flush shared_pool`.  Normally this is a terrible idea.  But on the few occasions where I've also had inexplicable problems with some very simple queries where it seemed like Oracle was acting crazy, this statement cleared the anomalies.

Comment: @sstan they won't accept to do that. That's only happening on prod so there is no possible way that they do this, it may impact business and my project is a very low priority.

Comment: @sstan my workaround is really simple : `select * from ( select * from myTable where mydate > '2015-05-31') where mydate > sysdate - 30` something like this... (But this shows how oracle interpreter is dumb - I wish I could work again with teradata)